WebSocket connection to 'ws://0.0.0.0:3000/ws' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_ADDRESS_INVALID
I´m building a electron forge application with webpack templates and react integration and since i did this command "npm run publish" this error is occuring and my aplication is not working. I´m following the documentation but nothing helps.
my webpack.main.config js
\`module.exports = {
/\*\*

* This is the main entry point for your application, it's the first file
* that runs in the main process.
 \*/
 entry: './src/main.js',
 // Put your normal webpack config below here
 module: {
 rules: require('./webpack.rules'),
 },

};\`

